# Leaflet popup disappear or moved over drawn polygon

Tags: leaflet, polygon, popup, leaflet-draw

If I would like to popup something over an actually drawn polygon, 
then it sometimes disappear or moved to the first point of the polygon.

[image: Polygon vs popup in leaflet]

https://jsfiddle.net/o149mgwj/19/

```
var drawnItems = new L.FeatureGroup();
map.addLayer(drawnItems);

var drawControlFull = new L.Control.Draw({
    draw: {
        polygon: {
          allowIntersection: false, // Restricts shapes to simple polygons
          drawError: {
            color: '#e1e100', // Color the shape will turn when intersects
            message: '<strong>Oh snap!<strong> you can\'t draw that!' // Message that will show when intersect
          },
          shapeOptions: {
            color: '#97009c'
          }
        },
        // disable toolbar item by setting it to false
        polyline: false,
        circle: false, // Turns off this drawing tool
        rectangle: false,
        marker: true,
        circlemarker: false
        },

    edit: {
        featureGroup: drawnItems,
        remove: true
    }
});

map.on("draw:created", function (e) {
    //var drawn_layer = e.layer;    
    var temp = drawnItems.addLayer(e.layer);
    //drawn_layer.addTo(drawnItems);

    var popupContent = 'blabla';        

    temp.bindPopup(popupContent, {keepInView: true, closeButton: true, autoClose: false, autoPan: false}).openPopup();

/*  if (e.layer instanceof L.Marker) {
        var popupCoords = e.layer.getLatLng();
    }
    if (e.layer instanceof L.Polygon) {
        var popupCoords = e.layer.getCenter();
    }

    var popup = L.popup()
        .setLatLng([popupCoords.lat, popupCoords.lng])
        .setContent(popupContent)
        .openOn(map); */

});
```

I have tried .css style manipulation as well, like:

```
.leaflet-interactive {
    z-index: 1;
}

.leaflet-popup-content-wrapper  {
    z-index: 1000 !important ;
}
```

Any idea to solve this issue?

Comment: @Incognitoo, Can you link your JSFiddle?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. I see two popups in your screenshot. What is the problem with the two?

Comment: Maybe test the code, then you will see that the popup in the polygon sometimes doesn't appear, sometimes moved from the center.

Comment: The JS fiddle would be nice. I assume that there is something wrong with this line: `var temp = drawnItems.addLayer(e.layer);`. You are effectively assigning the method `addLayer()` to a variable. Later you bind a popup to the method. I'm not sure why you get a popup at all (sometimes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I solved it. So I think it's fair if I share it:

```
map.on("draw:created", function (e) {
    var layer = e.layer;
    drawControlFull.remove();
    drawControlEditOnly.addTo(map);

    var popupContent = 'blaa!';

    drawnItems.addLayer(layer);

    if (layer instanceof L.Marker) {
        var popupCoords = e.layer.getLatLng();
        var popup = L.popup({offset: [0, -20], keepInView: true, closeButton: true, autoClose: false, autoPan: true, closeOnClick: false })
        .setLatLng([popupCoords.lat, popupCoords.lng])
        .setContent(popupContent)
        .openOn(map);
    }
    if (layer instanceof L.Polygon) {
        var popupCoords = e.layer.getCenter();
        var popup = L.popup({keepInView: true, closeButton: true, autoClose: false, autoPan: true, closeOnClick: false })
        .setLatLng([popupCoords.lat, popupCoords.lng])
        .setContent(popupContent)
        .openOn(map);       
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I can always repeat your problem shown in the video with Firefox, while it looks fine in other browsers.

[the video repeating the bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnG0f.jpg)

It is true that If you click other part of drawn polygon without drawing tool on, the popup moved (in this case the last point for closing the polygon)

looks like a bug in the Drawing tool with Firefox that closing the polygon with the last point triggers popup moved unexpectedly. I don't have time to go though its documentations, blocking the event to spawn a new popup on clicked location / moving the popup may helps. It is better to open a new issue for them to handle it. https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw/issues

Comment: please watch the video added.